# Any reason I should not switch to Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

We are thinking about using Jenkins as our CI server.  I used to use Bamboo in my last company. I don't love it, but it works alright.

Here is my short checklist.

- Git
- Maven
- FishEye
- Crucible/Gerrit
- Jira
- Support of distributed build farm
- Single sign-on with LDAP support

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Is this really a programming question? (Are you asking "Is Jenkins any good?" Answer: Yes. But question is pretty subjective.) Jenkins is free. Install it and try it.  I found it really easy to use.

Comment: I have a good feeling about it too.  But, I am not really an experienced release/build guy. I just want to make sure I didn't overlook any major limitation of Hudson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins supports (either natively or with plugins) Git, Maven, Jira, Gerrit, distributed builds, and LDAP support. I think it supports fisheye as well, but I could tell easily from my configuration. Of those, I've used Maven, distributed builds, and LDAP. At the very least, there is strong community support for Jenkins here, so if you have any issues once you get rolling the chances are your question is either already answered or will be quickly resolved for you.